# Select Case Is < 0 true on negative numbers

Tags: ms-access

What started as a simple validation code converted in something very paradoxical in my eyes.

The following code returns "Good work!" when I input a negative number in the InputBox popup

```
Dim myvar As String

myvar = InputBox("input a positive number, please")

If IsNumeric(myvar) Then
    myvar = CDbl(myvar)
    Select Case myvar
    Case Is < 0
        MsgBox "I need a positive number"
    Exit Sub
    Case Is > 0
        MsgBox "Good work!"
        [MyField] = myvar
        RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
        Me.Requery
    Exit Sub
    Case Else
        MsgBox "You entered '" & myvars & "'. I don't know what to do about"
    End Select
Else
    MsgBox "A Number, please"
End If
```

Is this really the best way to validate an InputBox?

Comment: Don't forget to account for 0 also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `myvar` is a `String`, `CDbl(myvar)` will get implicitly converted back to a string. Create a temporary numeric variable for the `Select Case`.

Comment: also, you don't need the `Exit Sub` after each Case, and in the case else, you have `myvars` instead of `myvar`. using `Option Explicit` will help you track down that type of error

Comment: This solved it. But do I really need two variables for a single inputbox? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @Hristo: if you want to avoid it, try putting it in the same line: `Select Case CDbl(myvar)`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with some of the other answers. Think about this code re-write (notice the second variable declared):

```
Dim myvar as String
Dim myDbl as Double

myvar = inputBox ("Input a positive number, please")

if isnumeric(myvar) then
    myDbl = cDbl(myvar)
else
    msgbox "Enter a number please"
    exit sub
end if


if mydbl <=0 then
    msgbox "I need a positive number"
else        'if mydbl > 0 then
    MsgBox "Good work!"
    [MyField] = myvar
    RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Me.Requery
end if
```

That would solve you problems by accounting for zero and declaring a separate variable as a double there. The if statement instead of the case is just preference I suppose. But now think about the two variables you have.

```
debug.print "MyVar is a string containing: " & myvar

debug.print cstr(cdbl(myvar)*2)    
'This forces myvar into a double(a number-type) to do math on it and then print it out
```

However, if you were to re-run the first print, you would see that myvar is still a string and can be used like a string. In VBA, unlike some other languages, variables are only what you declare them as. If you want to use them as other things, you have to declare another variable of the needed type.

TL;DR Think of them as different containers. Strings are circle boxes and doubles are square boxes. They might be able to hold similar stuff but the functionality of the containers is limited by their shape. In VBA you don't have a way to force a circle into a square so you have to make a whole second container and transfer the stuff over.